# Icons in the Navigation bar .NET core

Tags: razor, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to add cart icon in my Navigation bar and it is not working as expected. Below is what I tried

```
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark order-bottom box-shadow mb-3" style="background-color: #008cba; color: #ffffff;">
        <div class="container">
           <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Orders" asp-action="Index" asp-route-custEmail=@User.Identity.Name><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart">Cart </span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

The issue is the Icon is not showing up in the UI and it shows up like

[image]

Also how can I have Cart icon to show towards the right in the Navigation bar and leave other navigation as is. Please let me know what is that I am missing here

***** EDIT **********
Before adding reference

[image]

After adding reference the icon in the navigation appears but itremoves the Pagination

[image]

Comment: Do you have a reference of the glyphicons stylesheet?

Comment: @Anuraj No I hvaenot.. How can I add that refrence, I thought it was part of bootstrap

Comment: @Anuraj I added the reference in to my _Layout file still no change.. I have updated my question with what I tried.. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Now you're trying with Font awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

to replace

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Then put cart icon into `_LoginPartial`.
Layout:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark order-bottom box-shadow mb-3" style="background-color: #008cba; color: #ffffff;">
        <div class="container">
           <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1" style="width:600px">
                    
                </ul>
                <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

_LoginPartial:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Orders" asp-action="Index" asp-route-custEmail=@User.Identity.Name><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart">Cart </span></a>
    </li>
    @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <form class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
                <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
            </form>
        </li>
    }
    else
    {
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: The issue is If I add new references it is taking the Pagination I have implemented. I have updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Try this - Modify your code like this - `<span class="fas fa-shopping-cart">&nbsp;Cart </span>` instead of `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart">Cart </span>`

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-dark order-bottom box-shadow mb-3" style="background-color: #008cba; color: #ffffff;">
        <div class="container">
           <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li>
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Orders" asp-action="Index" asp-route-custEmail=@User.Identity.Name><span class="fas fa-shopping-cart">&nbsp;Cart </span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

I didn't added the reference of Bootstrap and Font Awesome.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anuraj_p/enu7mpxy/3) snippet

Comment: I tried to change to `class="fas fa-shopping-cart"`  the icon still doesnt show up.. I have the following References for the other styling to work  _Layout.cshtml   ` <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />`
   ` <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />`
   ` <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">` Do you know if I am missing something

Comment: `fas fa-shopping-cart` - Font Awesome Icons. If you like to use Bootstrap Icons, use this `class="bi bi-cart4"` . Checkout https://icons.getbootstrap.com/ for more information